# How to bypass the check constraint in sql

Tags: mysql, check-constraints

**Schema**

```
   create table course
        (course_id  varchar(8), 
         title      varchar(50), 
         dept_name  varchar(20),
         credits    numeric(2,0) check (credits > 0),
         primary key (course_id),
         foreign key (dept_name) references department (dept_name)
            on delete set null
        );
```

I wanted to add this data to the table, but I unable to add 0 credits.

> “CS-001”, titled “Weekly Seminar”, with 0 credits

**Insert Query**

```
INSERT INTO `course`(`course_id`, `title`, `credits`) VALUES ('CS-001','Weekly Seminar','0');
```

**Query result:**
[image: here]

Is there any other way to insert the same data without altering the table structure?

Comment: Please do NOT use "sql" as a tag - unless the question is about ansi standard sql - your question is very specific to your database (MySQL) so I used that tag. Note also that images are NOT encouraged, the error text could have been copy/pasted and that is preferrable. From site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**.—copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: You want a zero in a column that has extra code to disallow zeros? Why do you want to keep the constrain and at the same time render it useless? What does a zero-credit seminar mean? You graduate without having to learn anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `foreign_key_checks` option affects foreign key enforcement, not check constraint enforcement.

```
mysql> set foreign_key_checks=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `course`(`course_id`, `title`, `credits`) VALUES ('CS-001','Weekly Seminar','0');
ERROR 3819 (HY000): Check constraint 'course_chk_1' is violated.
```

You must use `ALTER TABLE`, but you don't have to drop the constraint.

```
mysql> alter table course alter check course_chk_1 not enforced;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO `course`(`course_id`, `title`, `credits`) VALUES ('CS-001','Weekly Seminar','0');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

But once you insert that row, you cannot re-enable the check constraint, because rows will be re-checked as the constraint is enabled.

```
mysql> alter table course alter check course_chk_1 enforced;
ERROR 3819 (HY000): Check constraint 'course_chk_1' is violated.
```

You could subsequently delete or update the rows that violate the check constraint, then re-enable the constraint.

If you need to be able to insert zero values to the `credits` column, then it seems like that `check (credits > 0)` isn't the right choice for that column. Maybe it needs to be `check (credits >= 0)`.